# Getting singleton behavior. Spring contexts questions

Tags: spring

I have been playing a bit with spring and have a question regarding getting singleton behavior on one of my classes. More specifically, I'm having a class called Cache which I would like to have singleton behavoir on. I'll start by posting the important parts of my actual code (an mdb, a servlet and a few xml files) and then elaborate on my question a bit more.

MessageReceiver.java

```
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private Cache cache;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        ... do stuff with cache
}
```

beanRefContext.xml

```
 <bean id="jar.context"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext" >

    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>spring-context.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>


<bean id="cache" class="com.company.myapp.cache.impl.CacheImpl"/>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>jar.context</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.myapp.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in my servlet I inject a Cache instance with the following

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
cache = (Cache) ctx.getBean("cache");
```

Although the injection of a Cache instance is working both in the servlet and mdb, I'm not getting the same instance in both cases. I know that generally beans are not singletons across different contexts and my first question is if that also (or neccessarily have to) apply also in a parent child context setting.

My second question (in case the above code isnt easy to modify in order to get the behavior that I want) is if there is either a standard way to get singleton behavior across multiple contexts or if I somehow could make my mdb and servlet live in the same context. I have tried playing with the latter idea a bit but with no success (because of lack of knowledge I guess...).

Comment: A singleton is once per context.  So if you only defined it in one context, you should get the behaviour you need.  Is it a spelling mistake that you use "Cache" in the servlet and "cache" in the XML?  If not, they are 2 different beans, and where is "Cache" defined?

Comment: @DaveSyer : Yes, it's a spelling mistake. I will edit the post.

Comment: It should work as long as the MDB and Servlet share a class loader.  How are they deployed?

Comment: @DaveSyer : The MDB lives in a jar, the Servlet in a war. Both of them are packaged in an ear which is deployed using jboss.

Comment: My guess then is that they don't share a SingletonBeanFactoryLocator because they both load that class separately.  You would need to put the Spring jars in a common class loader.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a the cache in a parent context would solve this.

If you do not want to go that way, you could also implement an [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) to instantiate the cache and save the singleton instance to a static field.